# Angular js placeholder issues in ie9

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have added placeholder in my partial page like below,

```
<input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter name" ng-class="{'error':form.name.$invalid}" ng-model="Name" required />
```

and implemented client side validation for text box.

```
if (this.name.$error.regEx) {
        $scope.errorList.push({              
            Message: "Invalid name"
        });
    }
```

I have created directive for regular expression. This code working fine in chrome and IE 10. But in IE 9, if i copy and paste the correct name in text box, it throws client side validation error(since it is taking place holder text as well). Can anyone help me out how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

IE9 does not support the `placeholder` attribute since it's an HTML5 property. There is very good solution given by **thomseddon**

```
angular.module('test', [])
.directive('placeholder', function($timeout){
    var i = document.createElement('input');
    if ('placeholder' in i) {
        return {}
    }
    return {
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs){
            if (attrs.type === 'password') {
                return;
            }
            $timeout(function(){
                elm.val(attrs.placeholder);
                elm.bind('focus', function(){
                    if (elm.val() == attrs.placeholder) {
                        elm.val('');
                    }
                }).bind('blur', function(){
                    if (elm.val() == '') {
                        elm.val(attrs.placeholder);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/thomseddon/4703810